# ¿Cómo iniciar sesión con diferentes perfiles en django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Debo hacer un sistema simple de asignación de tareas, y tengo tres roles: funcionario, asignador y administrador. La idea es que al logear, el funcionario tenga acceso solamente a la visualización de sus tareas propias, el asignador podrá visualizar, agregar, editar y eliminar tareas, y el administrador podrá visualizar, agregar, editar y eliminar tareas y, además, ver estadísticas. Necesito que cada usuario tenga acceso a una interfaz distinta, según el que se logea.